# How do I limit the rows I process in a CSV

Tags: python, csv

I know I could use a counter, but just wondering if there was something a bit more Pythonic.

At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
csvReader = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(data))
for row in csvReader:
   ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, limited to the first 10 rows

```
from itertools import islice

for row in islice(csvReader, 10):
    ...
```

Using [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

> `itertools.islice(iterable, stop)`
>
> `itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop[, step])`
>
> ---
>
> Make an iterator that returns selected elements from the iterable. If `start` is non-zero, then elements from the iterable are skipped until `start` is reached. Afterward, elements are returned consecutively unless `step` is set higher than one which results in items being skipped. If `stop` is `None`, then iteration continues until the iterator is exhausted, if at all; otherwise, it stops at the specified position. Unlike regular slicing, `islice()` does not support negative values for `start`, `stop`, or `step`. Can be used to extract related fields from data where the internal structure has been flattened (for example, a multi-line report may list a name field on every third line).